# Firestore Timestamp is (seconds: 0, nanoseconds: 0) when using Retrofit

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, retrofit

I have the problem related to parsing Firestore Timestamp in Android app.

#### Summary

In my Firebase Firestore, I have a collection of comments. Every comment looks like this

[image: comment]

> (time is of type Timestamp)

I've built REST API using Cloud Functions. There is a GET method for comments endpoint. Sharing the whole code doesn't have sense, the important fact is, the response from that endpoint looks like this

[image: comment_response]

As you can see, the response looks good, everything's okay.

#### The problem

Now, I have the Android app using Retrofit to communicate with the API. It makes a request to aforementioned endpoint and gets the response (response is a `<List<CommentResponse>>`).

```
import com.google.firebase.Timestamp

data class CommentResponse(
    val placeId: String,
    val userUid: String,
    val userDisplayName: String,
    val userPhotoUrl: String,
    val time: Timestamp,
    val text: String
)
```

But when I do `Log.d(response.body)`, I get (I cut the unimportant data)

```
[CommentResponse(placeId=opactwo, userUid=e09E...82, userDisplayName=Bartek Pacia, userPhotoUrl=https: .../photo.jpg, time=Timestamp(seconds=0, nanoseconds=0), text=This place is very beautiful :D)]
```

Timestamp vanished. It's not null, but it points to the beggining of the Epoch (1.1.1970). It's just 0 sec, 0 nanosec. I don't use any custom converters or whatever, just the "beginner level Retrofit".

And, well, that's it.
I've no idea why the Timestamp changes to 0,0.

I'd be very grateful if somebody could help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `time` is JsonObject which contains `seconds` and `nanoseconds` keys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assuming that Retrofit knows how to deserialize the timestamp based on its default JSON serialization from the server.  It doesn't know how to do that.  You're going to have to manage that yourself.

When your function serializes the timestamp, it's using the default serialization of the contents of the document.  It's looking at the [Timestamp](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Timestamp.html) object and saying "hey, there's an object, so in order to serialize that, I'm just going to copy all of its properties into the output".  If you look at the [source for Timestamp](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/timestamp.js.html#source-line-109), you'll see that it's using properties _seconds and _nanoseconds to hold the components of the Timestamp.  So, that explains the JSON output you see.

On the Java (or Kotlin) client side, all that is effectively going to be just a Map object, and the type information is gone (and it wouldn't be helpful as JavaScript stuff doesn't simply map to Java stuff).  No one knows that it was a Timestamp type object that came across the wire.  All it knows is that there's an object with _seconds and _nanoseconds.

What you need to do is put some smarts into your code (maybe as a hint to Retrofit in the form of a custom converter) to help it recognize what's in that `time` JSON object, and convert that to a Timestamp object locally using the [java Timestamp constructor](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#Timestamp(long,%20int)).

Or, if you don't mind losing a few nanoseconds of precision, just have the function convert the Timestamp into a the time in milliseconds, send that over the wire, and have the client simply convert that to a java Date object.

**You might also want to stop depending on the internal details of the JavaScript Timestamp object.** Since _seconds and _nanoseconds are effectively private details, you are depending on something that might change in the future.  *Consider instead explicitly serializing the Timestamp in your function using the data from its public methods getSeconds() and getNanoseconds().*

Comment: Thanks for such an exhaustive response. Nanoseconds doesn't matter to me. I'll return miliseconds in the API response and parse it on the client side to Date :)